# TCP checksum calculation goes wrong

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to get the correct TCP checksum but it fails. I am using C++ and I get the packets of my local network with winpcap and I've tried to calculate their tcp checksums (I've put the correct filter to get only tcp packets). But when I compare my calculated checksum with wireshark tcp checksums, they are not the same.

This is the code I did with C++, it uses bitmap to detect the bit carries.

```
u_char* tcp_checksum(const u_char* data, int size)
{
    u_char *checksum = new u_char[2]();
    uint16_t sumando = 0;
    bitset<17> total;

    //add ip src and ip dst
    for (int i = 26; i < 33; i++){
        total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        if (total[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
        i++;
    }

    //add el zero byte and number of protocol
    total = sumando + (uint16_t)(0x06);
    sumando += (uint16_t)(0x06);
    if (total[16] == 1)
        sumando++;

    /*here I should add the tcp length to complete the tcp pseudo header but i    didnt add anything because I dont know to calculate the tcp len correctly but its not a problem because a lot of times is cero and the tcp still failing.*/

    //okay we have just calculated the pseudoheader.

    //add all tcp header except the 2 bytes of the checksum (20 bytes normally)
    for (int i = 34; i < 54; i++){
        if (i != 50 && i != 52){//no sumo ni padding ni checksum.
            total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
            sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
            if (total[16] == 1)
                sumando++;
        }
        //
        if (i == 52) break;
        i++;
    }


    //add the tcp payload in 16 bits each adding.
    for (int i = 55; i < tamaño - 1; i++){//tamaño - 1
        total = sumando + (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        sumando += (uint16_t)((datos[i] << 8) + datos[i + 1]);
        if (total[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
        i++;
    }
    if (tamaño % 2 == 0){
        total = sumando + (uint16_t)((0x00 << 8) + datos[tamaño]);
        sumando += (uint16_t)((0x00 << 8) + datos[tamaño]);
        if (total[16] == 1)
            sumando++;
    }

    //i get the complementary and i divided the u_short (16 bits) (uint16_t) in 2 bytes which i return
    sumando = sumando & 0xFFFF;
    sumando = ~sumando;
    checksum[0] = (sumando >> 8) & 0x00FF;
    checksum[1] = sumando & 0x00FF;
    return checksum;
    }
```

Okay, when i try to compare between real tcp checksum bytes and my tcp checksum its not the same:

> ```
> printf("%x%x==", pkt_data[50], pkt_data[51]);
> u_char *c = new u_char[2]();
> c= tcp_checksum(pkt_data, header->caplen);
> printf("%x%x\n", c[0], c[1]);
> cout << endl;
> delete c;
> ```

I get different bytes, normally the bytes 51 and 52 of a packet tcp belong to tcp checksum. When I output them, they are not the same.

Comment: Can't you compare your checksum code with what wireshark does in userspace, or maybe check the linux kernel and see how it is done there?

Comment: That is not the problem, because i have read that the "checksum offloading" affects also at IP checksum, and in this case i calculated the IP checksum with the same method and it was succesfull. The problem is in the code, so please be concerned about the code, and not to problems that dont exist. My code is wrong, and i posted here to correct it, and not to talk about "checksum offloading" when my code have 100 errors that are not corrected.

Comment: Have you followed the RFC? See [TCP Checksum Function Design](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1071#section-2.4.4.5)

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare your results with wireshark, at least not without turning off [checksum offloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine).

Checksums of packets captured through libpcap/winpcap are [often wrong](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvChecksums.html) due to checksum offloading performed by the network interface card.

Comment: (Posted for [Kaxperday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5615711/kaxperday))That is not the problem, because i have read that the "checksum offloading" affects also at IP checksum, and in this case i calculated the IP checksum with the same method and it was succesfull.

The problem is in the code, so please be concerned about the code, and not to problems that dont exist. My code is wrong, and i posted here to correct it, and not to talk about "checksum offloading" when my code have 100 errors that are not corrected.